# What exactly are traits and mixins?

Tags: mixins, traits, paradigms

I stumbled over `traits` as I took a look at `C++` code some time ago. If I recall correctly they were used to define strings out of chars. And I got told, that one could also define some kind of 'strings' out of `double` with traits - which I didn't quite get.

Today I read an article about aspect-oriented programming, where they drew a parallel to traits and mixins. So what exactly are traits and mixins? What is their right to exist?